# OpenAI Assistant causing memory leaks

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, memory, openai-api

I'm trying to run a flask app that uses OpenAI's Assistant, but it stops working after a day running on the server and in the terminal I see "Killed". What's causing it in the code? Can I do something to fix it? Perhaps my `kill_idle_sessions()` function isn't enough.

```py
import os.path
import sqlite3
import threading
import time
import uuid
import traceback
import logging

import openai
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from openai import OpenAI

db = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
dblock = threading.Lock()

logger = logging.getLogger('site')

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

client = OpenAI(api_key='...')
assistant = client.beta.assistants.retrieve('...')

print(f'Assistant loaded: {assistant.name} ({assistant.id}')

sessions = {
  # session_id: Session
}


def kill_idle_sessions():
  for sid in list(sessions.keys()):
    scls = sessions[sid]
    if time.time() - scls.last_request > 60*15:
      # kill session
      del sessions[sid]
      logger.info(f'killed {sid} due to idle')


class Session:
  def __init__(self, session_id):
    self.session_id = session_id
    self.thread = client.beta.threads.create()
    self.last = 0
    self.last_request = time.time()

  def wait_on_run(self, run):
    while run.status == "queued" or run.status == "in_progress":
      run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
        thread_id=self.thread.id,
        run_id=run.id,
      )
      time.sleep(0.5)
    return run

  def ask(self, question, retries=0):
    # while we're here... lets kill idle sessions
    self.last_request = time.time()
    kill_idle_sessions()

    if retries > 5:
      return "Sorry, I'm having trouble on my side, please try again later."

    try:
      message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=self.thread.id,
        role="user",
        content=question
      )
    except openai.BadRequestError as e:
      logger.error(f'Error: {e}', exc_info=True)
      time.sleep(3)
      return self.ask(question, retries=retries + 1)

    run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(thread_id=self.thread.id, assistant_id=assistant.id)
    run = self.wait_on_run(run)

    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=self.thread.id, order="asc", after=message.id)
    return "\n\n".join(m.content[0].text.value for m in messages.data)


@app.route('/ask', methods=['POST'])
def ask():
  """API method to ask the assistant a question"""
  try:
    # has session id cookie?
    session_id = request.json.get('session_id', None)
    has_session = session_id is not None

    if not has_session:
      session_id = uuid.uuid4().hex

    if has_session and session_id not in sessions:
      return jsonify(dict(type="error", error="Invalid session id"))

    question = request.json['question']

    resp = dict(type="success", response="What do you mean by that...?")

    if not has_session:
      resp['session_id'] = session_id
      sessions[session_id] = Session(session_id)

    sess: Session = sessions[session_id]

    ans = sess.ask(question)

    # save to database
    ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') or request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR') or "unknown"
    # print(ip)

    with dblock:
      db.execute('INSERT INTO queries (ip, question, answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (ip, question, ans))
      db.commit()

    resp['response'] = ans

    return jsonify(resp)
  except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    logger.error(f'Error: {e}', exc_info=True)
    return jsonify(dict(type="error", error=f"server error occured, check logs."))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=False, ssl_context=..., host='0.0.0.0')
```

I tried to free unused memory with the `kill_idle_sessions()` function, but I still get "Killed" in my terminal.

Comment: Normally that's from being killed externally. Are you running on your own machine or some server? If on a server, is there a max runtime policy that might kill your process at some point?

Comment: its a digitalocean droplet, how can i check?

Comment: I think you can trust the output: they kill your process. You'll need to look up the run time policies for your droplet tier. Which means this is not really a programming question, but one to send to digitalocean's customer support.